# How to map JavaBean fields with Casssandra table column?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I am using spark-sql.2.4.1v , datastax-java-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8.

> I have cassandra table like

```
create company(company_id int PRIMARY_KEY, company_name text);
```

> JavaBean as below

```
@Table(name = "company")
class CompanyRecord(
 @PartitionKey(0)
 @Column(name="company_id")
 Integer companyId;
@Column(name="company_name")
 String companyName;
//getter and setters
//default & parametarized constructors
)
```

> I have spark code below save the data into cassandra table.

```
Dataset<Row> latestUpdatedDs = joinUpdatedRecordsDs.select("company_id", "company_name"); /// select from other source like xls sheet

Encoder<CompanyRecord> comanyEncoder =  Encoders.bean(CompanyRecord.class);         
Dataset<CompanyRecord> inputDs = latestUpdatedDs.as(comanyEncoder );


 inputDs 
        .write()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("table","company")
        .option("keyspace",  "ks_one")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save();
```

**Giving error like below**

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator - failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 176, Column 75: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 176, Column 75: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:12124)

 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table ks_one.company: 
 companyId, companyName
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns.selectFrom(ColumnSelector.scala:44)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:385)
```

**> Question:**

Even though I am using annotation for mapping , why I am getting error ?
How to fix this without changing the Java Bean field names ( i.e. from companyId to company_id) ?